# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
elif (int(Data[1])) <= 0 or int(Data[1]> 12):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Везде проставил int но все равно не могу понять почему вылетает тайперорр

```py
DateOfBirthday = input("Введите дату рождения в формате ДД.MM.ГГГГ\n")
splitDateOfBirthday = DateOfBirthday.split(".")
startStudy = int(input("Введите дату начала обучения в формате ГГГГ\n"))

def CheckData(Data):
    MaxData = date.today()
    try:
        if(int(Data[0])) <= 0 or (int(Data[0])>31): #дата на правильность ввода
            if(int(Data[1]) % 2 == 0 and int(Data[0]) > 30): #чек даты если месяц четный
                print("Ошибка: В этом месяце меньше 30 дней")
            print(f"Ошибка в этом месяце не может быть {int(Data[1])}")
        elif (int(Data[1])) <= 0 or int(Data[1]> 12):
            print(f"Ошибка: в этом году не может быть {int(Data[1])}")
        elif (int(Data[2]) <= 0 or int(Data[2]) > MaxData.year):
            print("Ошибка: такого года не существует")
        else:
            return Data
    except ValueError:
        print("Дата была задана в неправильно порядке ")
```

Comment: 1. Ты забыл задать вопрос. 2. Перед тем, как задать вопрос, ты забыл прочитать текст ошибки и поискать решение самостоятельно. 3. В вопрос ты забыл включить полное сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 2):

```
        elif (int(Data[1])) <= 0 or int(Data[1]> 12):
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Скобка не там закрыта. Вы сначала сравниваете строку с числом, а потом уже преобразуете результат этого сравнения в `int`.

Comment: в python есть такое сравнение:  if 0 < i < 31:

Comment: @Виктор Есть. Только оно для соединения условий через `and`, а не через `or`.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку вам показали, я покажу как проверить валидность даты, без того, чтобы изобретать велосипед, поскольку он уже готов. (конечно, если это не ради учебы и понимания, как это сделать)

```py
import time

def is_valid_date(date_for_checking):
    try:
        time.strptime(date_for_checking, '%d.%m.%Y')
        return True
    except:
        print("Дата была задана не верно")
        return False


dateOfBirthday = input("Введите дату рождения в формате ДД.MM.ГГГГ\n")
isValid = is_valid_date(dateOfBirthday)
print(isValid)
```